# Image not rendering in dompdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am using codeIgniter and dompdf for my application for generating pdfs. The below code is the code which i am using to display an image.

```
<div class=\"block_head\">
     <h2>Image display</h2>";
     $image_location = "/images/xxx.png";
     $html .="<img src=\"".$image_location."\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\" />
</div>";
```

I tested and debugged all ways whether i am doing something wrong. Like this first i checked whether the path is wrong. This is path on the server. It's correct. I tested by echoing $html also it's showing perfectly path. When i clicked on that path image is displaying. But when i am trying to render it in pdf it's not displaying.

Note: PDF is generating perfectly without image.

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? You've got PHP intermingled with HTML.

Comment: it's confidential and there is no error in that code. This is the code block which i use to display image

Comment: OK, I'd give you my answer but that's confidential as well ;) I mean, are you `echo`ing that div? Because if you are, you aren't doing it correctly. Or are you setting it to a variable? What's going on?

Comment: I think in dompdf we don't need to echo any thing. When we try to render the $html string using $dompdf->load_html($html);  it will automatically display image and any html data.

Comment: Ah I see now. You need to manipulate the pdf object like `$pdf->image($path, $w, $y,  $img_w, $img_h);`, enable remote, use full path, enable php? https://www.google.com/search?q=dompdf%20images%20not%20showing

Answer (score 1):

Try as below

> if you are providing full URI to the image it is treated as external,
>   so defined costant DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE must be set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading this document into dompdf using `$dompdf->load_html($html);`? If so then you're probably running into a context problem. When you load a document in this manner dompdf has no knowledge of the document base path. Because of this it assumes you are working from the local file system. In this context the root path "/" translates to the root of the local file system not the root of the web content directory. Either use a path relative to the PHP file implementing dompdf, or specify the full path in the current files system.